# Where can I get a list of all HTML elements and their applicable CSS style attributes?

Tags: html, css

I would like a list of all known HTML elements (not just the ones in my document) that shows, for each element, the CSS style attributes that can be applied to the element. I waste a lot of time trying things like this:

```css
td {
  height: 20px;
}
```

That, of course, does nothing (not even throw an error). So I Google "how can I set a fixed height for a `<td>` element", read through the hits, and find out that "height" is not an available style attribute for `<td>`. I need to wrap the `<td>` in a `<div>` instead.

So what I'm looking for is a complete dictionary of HTML elements showing the style attributes that are recognized by each. I have looked in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML -- it shows *almost* everything there is to know about every HTML element -- but NOT the style attributes that work for the element.

Suggestions?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: If you wrap a `<td>` within a `<div>` you've just written invalid HTML. A `<td>` can only appear as the direct child of a `<tr>` (if you're trying to write *valid* HTML).

Answer (score 1):

May you have to lookup the other way around.
[Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#properties) is an overview about CSS elements. There are also hints for usage. For example for height:

> Applies to:   all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table columns, and column groups

Comment: Tx -- you're probably right. My design process starts with defining the overall structure of the page -- where tables, input fields, buttons, etc. will go. So first I have all the html elements in place. Next I define CSS styles needed to shape things the way I want. So the natural sequence for me is "Here is a table row. I need to stick some blank space above it. I wonder how to do that?" If I have to consult a list of all CSS attributes, it may take me a while to go through all the hundreds (thousands?) of attributes to see which ones will work.